# barely runs, it seems like no fuel or some electrical problem, but it has no oil pressure, what could this be?

Tags: chevrolet, oil, fuel-system, silverado

My 2006 Chevrolet Silverado 3/4 ton with a 6.0L V8 (LQ9). Has no oil. But it seems like it's not getting gas. Or it's an electrical problem. Truck barely runs, what can this be?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! No oil or no oil pressure?

Answer (score 0):

It can't run without oil pressure. It **shouldn't** run without oil pressure.

The electric fuel pump gets power from 3 sources, the fuel pump relay when starting, an oil pressure sensor when running and a test connection.

Figure out the oil pressure problem first.